# use callouts instead of alerts for input error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to pop up a user error message like "User name must be six characters" in a callout or bubble rather than

```
alert("User name must be six characters");
```

?

The callout shouldn't require any user interaction and should disappear on its own after some given period of time (like two seconds).

Comment: have you looked into jQuery UI dialogs?  Bootstrap has modal support as well.  There's a ton of options out there.

Comment: I looked at JQM popups and they do seem to be the closest to what I'm looking for. I will do some experimenting over the weekend. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom popup CSS is the main contender. All Javascript needs to do is toggle it under the desired condition.

```
<script>
  function popup(){
    warning.style.display='block';
    setTimeout(function(){
      warning.style.display='none';
    },2000);
  }
</script>

<body>
  <button onclick='popup()'>Button</button>
  <div id='warning' style='display:none;'>DONT DO THAT!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of the callout that pops up in a windows envirnment (XP) when you're out of memory for example. Generally callouts have an arrowhead that can be pointed at the object necessitating the message.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite neat:

```
<head> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript"> 
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){

  // Initialise the popup widget
  $('#errmsgDiv').popup();

  // Register a new user
  $(document).on('click', '#Register', function(evnt) {
    if (userName == "" || password == "" || emailAddress == "") {
//      alert("Complete all the input fields");
      errmsgPopper("Complete all the input fields");
      evnt.stopImmediatePropagation();
      return false;
    }
  });

  // Popup error message for 2 seconds
  function errmsgPopper(msg){
    $('#errmsgDiv').html(msg).popup('open');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#errmsgDiv').popup('close');
    },2000);
  }

</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
.
.
.
  <div id="errmsgDiv" data-role="popup"><p>msg text</p></div>
</body>
```

It still requires some work in that the popup needs to position itself over the error field with an arrow pointing at the error field. Will add these later.

The only issue I have is that the

```
  $('#UserName').focus();
```

doesn't give UserName the focus anymore (like it did when using the alert)